# Indigenous inhabitants in Recluce universe

Tags: saga-of-recluce

Having recently re-read most of the [Saga of Recluce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Saga_of_Recluce) by L E Modesitt Jr., I've started to wonder about the pre-existing civilisations/countries that existed on Candar or elsewhere on the world.

The Angels landed last in the Westhorn mountains, so it is definite that the Rationalists and other cultures preceded them.

I think it's also true (from a reading of the short story "The Vice Marshal's Trial" in Recluce Tales) mentions that the Western lands of Candar were unpopulated due to the presence of the the Great Forest, and as it would be isolated this is where the Rationalists chose to land and create Cyador.

The question that has come to my mind however is how the original human settlers in Candar, Hamor etc. came to be there?  Was this through convergent evolution or are they the descendants of even another earlier, failed, colony?

Is there anything from the author that anyone has come across either in the books or elsewhere that outlines the answer to this question?